# Tomcat access in Coldfusion 11

Tags: java, tomcat, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I just switched from using Coldfusion 9 to using Coldfusion 11. Coldfusion9 included JRun as its application server, Coldfusion 11 is supposed to be using a custom version of Tomcat.

When I was using Coldfusion 9 I was able to use the JRun backend to deploy a few Java application WAR files as well. With the switch to Tomcat I was thinking it would be possible to do the same, just using Tomcat instead of JRun.

As of now, I have not been able to find a way to access the Tomcat instance running Coldfusion 11. When looking through the normal documentation there appears to be a line in the Server.xml for tomcat to enable access over port 8500. When I uncomment this line in the file and restart the server, the port is still not showing anything on it.

Is it possible to do this on the custom Tomcat version? Has anyone else tried with any luck?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: This might be a good question for serverfault.com

Comment: This may be helpful https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Installing+the+J2EE+Configuration#InstallingtheJ2EEConfiguration-InstallColdFusioninWindowsJ2EEconfiguration

Comment: These may be helpful as well http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion-tomcat.html and this http://www.carehart.org/presentations/cf10_on_tomcat.pdf (They reference ColdFusion 10 but that is when Adobe switched to Tomcat.)